# How to change the code of a website so that the the "mobile" version responds in a specific way?

Tags: javascript, html, deployment, handlebars.js

I am tasked with removing a navigation bar that functions fine on the general sized webpage version of a site, which, when reduced from left-to-right in a manner that matches the size of a mobile device, should not display.

I am confused on how to change this in the primary webpages code base without affecting how the navigation bar looks normally.

Do code bases for webpages have a version for both regular and mobile? How should I approach this issue?

Comment: This is not a simple one-solution issue.  Some sites do maintain separate mobile versions (basically small screens and/or touch screens), others use responsive layout designs so that the same content renders properly (well, "nicely") on any size screen.

Comment: Typically the same HTML/CSS/JS is served, regardless of whether the visitor is on mobile or desktop. You then use CSS @media queries to modify the presentation based on the screen width. You can then do things like apply `display: none` to a specific DOM element based on screen width. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to completely remove the navbar on narrower screens, you can use CSS and set a media query for a specific width.
Here's an example assuming the `nav-bar` component is inside of a larger html page.

```
<div class="nav-bar">
...navbar stuff...
</div>
```

---

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .nav-bar{
     display: none
  }
}
```

What the above code does is on screens that are 480px and narrower, it will set the display of the `nav-bar` element to none.  That will hide it from the page.  You can use media queries to further style the page for a mobile experience.